# Ассоциативные массивы

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток. Пробую изучить ассоциативные массивы. Имеется:
**UPD**

```
import java.util.*;


class Map {
    int a;
    String value;
    String key;
    HashMap<String, String> map;
   Map(){
       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
       map.put("key1", "value1");
       map.put("key2", "value2");
       map.put("key3", "value3");

   }
   int getSize(){
       return map.size();
   }

   String getValue(String key) {
       this.key = key;
       return map.get(key);
   }
}

public class Pr10_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map mp = new Map();
        System.out.println(mp.getSize());
        System.out.println(mp.getValue("key1"));  
    } 
}
```

Пытаюсь по `key1` получить значение `value` методом `getValue`, но редактор подчеркивает map в строке `return map.get(key);`.Тоже самое было и с `getSize()`, пришлось по другому сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста, может я как то неправильно запрашиваю значение? Или объявляю что-то неправильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы переписал класс так:

```
class Map {
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    Map(){
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key1", "value1");
        map.put("key2", "value2");
        map.put("key3", "value3");
    }

    int getSize(){
        return map.size();
    }

    String getValue(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Получается в том коде я второй раз объявлял `map` и соответственно получал NPE. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что переменная `map` из метода `getValue` не видна

```
class Map {
    int a;
    String value;
    String key;
    HashMap<String, String> map;
    Map(){
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("key1", "value1");
        map.put("key2", "value2");
        map.put("key3", "value3");
        a = map.size();
    }

    int getSize(){
        return a;
    }

    String getValue(String key) {
        this.key = key;
        return map.get(key);
    }
}
```

Пробуйте так

Comment: Спасибо, map стала доступной, правда теперь почему то даже на `return map.size();` получаю NPE